# Sinon cannot find method 'spy'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am trying to climb the learning curve on using require.js/mocha/chai/sinon with backbone apps.  When I run [this test](https://github.com/ErikEvenson/spa-testing-study/blob/bcc5b71b3b6f8b24f7e8d01673b50682498ee1b2/test/spec/hello.spec.js):

```
define([
    "chai",
    "sinon"
], function(chai, sinon){
    var expect = chai.expect;

    describe("Trying out the test libraries", function(){
        describe("Chai", function(){
            it("should be equal using 'expect'", function(){
                expect(hello()).to.equal("Hello World");
            });
        });

        describe("Sinon.JS", function(){
            it("should report spy called", function(){
                var helloSpy = sinon.spy(window, "hello");

                expect(helloSpy.called).to.be.false;
                hello();
                expect(helloSpy.called).to.be.true;
                hello.restore();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'spy'` [on the line where helloSpy is defined](https://github.com/ErikEvenson/spa-testing-study/blob/bcc5b71b3b6f8b24f7e8d01673b50682498ee1b2/test/spec/hello.spec.js#L16).  Why?  Note that the first test passes.

Here is the full project:

https://github.com/ErikEvenson/spa-testing-study/tree/bcc5b71b3b6f8b24f7e8d01673b50682498ee1b2.

Take care to use that particular commit.

Comment: Have you checked that `sinon` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I did and it is not.  It is an object, created by sinon.js, but it does not have a spy() method.

Comment: I'd have a look at the require.js set up then. I'm just throwing a few ideas at the wall to see what sticks; sorry I can't be more specific, I'm not that familiar with these tools.

Comment: I think you are right -- I suspect that sinon is not able to find its the directory that spy.js is in -- but I'm not sure how to remedy that...

Comment: Is there perhaps a `sinon.sinon.spy`?

Comment: Nope.  And the docs are pretty clear it is sinon.spy(...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here turns out to be that the bower repository for sinon is unusable as is per [this issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/119).  Sinon has to be built first and doing `bower install sinon` just pulls the Sinon.JS repo down.  Using `bower install sinonjs` instead of `bower install sinon` works, but gives an earlier version number.

Answer (score 4):

From @Erik link.

`install --save-dev sinonjs-built`

This will get you build version of sinon.

### Edit

a another bower version ( as @Erik suggested above) may be found in https://github.com/blittle/sinon.js

one can install it via 
`install --save-dev sinonjs`

### Edit 2

from `sinon github`:

> Important: AMD needs pre-built version
>     Sinon.JS as source doesn't work with AMD loaders (when they're asynchronous, like loading via script tags in the browser). For that you will have to use a pre-built version. You can either build it yourself or get a numbered version from http://sinonjs.org.

#### Solution: Tell bower the direct link of sinon file

You can edit the `bower.json` file. and instead of writing version just pass a `url` for the `file` i.e

```
[...]
"devDependencies": {
     "chai": "~1.10.0",
    "sinon": "http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.12.2.js#*",
 },
[...]
```

Comment: This is a third party build that's not kept up-to-date with the latest sinon releases.

Comment: @demisx, thank update the link to a better bower version.. but i dont know if its up to date